# How to pass html form information between iframes on google sites

Tags: javascript, html, google-sites

I am relatively new to html/ javascript, and I am trying to use google sites to build a simple store, that will send orders to a google sheet. At present, I am having difficulty passing data between iframes. In the first iframe, I am testing this snippet of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<input type="text" id="texttest">
<button onclick="store()" type="button">Store</button>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function store() {
    var myinput = document.getElementById("texttest");
    sessionStorage.setItem("texttest", myinput.value);
</script>
```

And in the second iframe, this snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p id="output"></p>
</html>
<script>
document.getElementByID("output").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("texttest");
</script>
```

The idea is essentially for a user to scroll through the option, input in certain fields the type and quantity of the item they want, and for those selections to be collected at the end and sent to a google sheet. However, the code below is not displaying the text entered in the "texttest" field in the "output" iframe. Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: Make sure that the iframe is on the same domain, otherwise that would be cross-site scripting.If both are on the same domain you could use local storage.